# Magento 2: Save custom shipping method's custom attribute in IWD one page checkout

Tags: magento2, shipping, third-party-module

I have enabled IWD one page checkout and then added my storepickup shipping method (as another extension) with custom shipping attributes like **delivery date** and **store** fields. But I could not set those custom attributes to quote and so in order object.